# Questions regarding Bockstein Spectral Sequence (McCleary's book)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, spectral-sequences

I have some questions regarding Bockstein homomorphism in John McCleary's book (pg 455-456).

[image]

Q1) Is there a typo, is it supposed to be $\bar{u}\in H_n(X;\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z})$?

[image]
Q2) How do we see that $\partial(c)\neq 0$?

Q3) How do we conclude that $\partial(c)=rv$?

Q4) How does the boundary homomorphism $\partial$ actually look like explicitly in this case, and how do we know it takes $\bar{u}$ to $\{v\}\in H_{n-1}(X)$?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1) Yes, it looks like a typo.

Q2) If $\partial c=0$, then $c \otimes 1$ would be in the image of $\text{red}_r$ and so the homology class $\overline{u}$ would go to zero under $\partial$.

Q3) The boundary map in $C_*(X) \otimes \mathbb{Z}/r$ is $\partial \otimes 1$. So $0=\partial (c \otimes 1) = (\partial c) \otimes 1$ means that $\partial c$ goes to zero when you reduce mod $r$, which means that it is in the image of multiplication by $r$.

Q4) The whole point of McCleary's discussion is to describe $\partial$ in this case. That is, he is taking the general description of the boundary map in homology arising from a short exact sequence of chain complexes, and he is analyzing what happens here. So I think this passage from the book already answers your question.

Comment: I think for Q2, you can actually ignore the $\partial(c)\neq0$ assumption, since it doesn't change what follows.

Comment: Thanks. This is immensely helpful.

Comment: @SteveD Thanks. I was also puzzled why we need $\partial(c)\neq 0$. We can always conclude $\partial(c)=rv$, where $v$ could be 0.